# Undefined array index

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array structure (from a JavaScript object through JQuery AJAX):

```
[column_id]
    [column_content_id]
        [content]
            .....
        [options]
            .....
        [styles]
            .....
```

I go through the array with:

```
foreach($this->rom['columns'] as $column_id => $columns) {
    // add columns
    $this->add_column($column_id, $this->id, $columns['options']['column-width']);
    // content
    foreach($columns as $content_id => $content) {
        // assign values
        $values = array(
            'styles'        => $content['styles'], 
            'options'       => $content['options'],
            'style_class'   => 'is-cc-style', 
            'in_column'     => true, 
            'id'            => str_replace('#', '', $mc_content_id),
            'column_id'     => $column_id,
            'content_type'  => $content['content_type'],
            'options_class' => 'is-cc-option'
        );
    }
}
```

Everything works well, except that I receive the following notices:

```
Notice: Undefined index: styles
Notice: Undefined index: options
Notice: Undefined index: content_type
```

How can I avoid this? At the moment I use:

```
if(isset($content['styles'])) {
    $content['styles'] = '';
}
```

But I guess that's not how it's supposed to be.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Is the lack of a closing `]` on this line `if(isset($content['styles')) {` a typo?

Comment: yes sorry i edited it, it was just a copy paste problem, its correct in the php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to return an empty string if the property is not set, and what you're using looks exactly like a syntax error to me ?

Here's how I'd do it

```
    $values = array(
        'styles'        => isset($content['styles']) ? $content['styles'] : "", 
        'options'       => isset($content['options']) ? $content['options'] : "",
        'style_class'   => 'is-cc-style', 
        'in_column'     => true, 
        'id'            => str_replace('#', '', $mc_content_id),
        'column_id'     => $column_id,
        'content_type'  => isset($content['content_type']) ? $content['content_type'] : "",
        'options_class' => 'is-cc-option'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get notices like this sometimes in php when you try to assign something that is NULL to a variable (it depends on the type of errors you have turned on), I am guessing that styles, options and or content_type are nullable? If so you can use an @ to suppress the warning like so:

```
    $values = array(
        'styles'        => @$content['styles'], 
        'options'       => @$content['options']
    );
```

or if you want to set it to a default value adeneo's solution would be best.